# Maximum backlog value for Windows port

Tags: java, windows, ports, backlog

It seems that there is an upper limit of ~200 for the backlog queue on Windows ports.
Is it true? And if so, can i change the limit?

I'm doing ServerSocket.accept(backlog) on a Windows XP Professional.

Should i move to Windows Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/advanced.html#backlog) it's even less. They say 5 for standard windows, 200 for windows server.

This [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B142641&x=11&y=14) is said to explain how to increase it - I just forwarded the link, didn't understand it ;)

Comment: The link is broken after 12 years :(, does anyone have another link?